# Issue Loading css into Cake PHP

Tags: jquery, css, cakephp

I am getting the following error and have not found much information about it, how can it be solved?. I would appreciate any help, all the other jquery is working properly.

```
    The stylesheet jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css 
was not loaded because its MIme type, "text /html",is not "text/css"
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here is a piece of the code.

```
        echo $this->Html->css('jquery-iu-1.8.16.custom');
        echo $this->Html->css('jquery.rating');
        echo $this->Html->css('dark.datetimepicker');
        echo $this->Html->css('admintable');
        echo $this->Html->css('pager');
        echo $this->Html->css('specialtablemenu');
        echo $this->Html->css('stylemaincontent');
        echo $this->Html->css('stylessidemenu');
        echo $this->Html->css('stylestopmenu');

         echo $this->Html->script('jquery.js');
         echo $this->Html->script('jquery.min.js');
         echo $this->Html->script('jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js');
         echo $this->Html->script('jquery.rating.js');
         echo $this->Html->script('jquery.MetaData.js');
         echo $this->Html->script('jquery.rating.pack.js');
         echo $this->Html->script('jquery.validate.js');
         echo $this->Html->script('javascript.js');
         echo $this->Html->script('ui.datetimepicker.js');
         echo $this->Html->script('paging.js');
         echo $this->Html->script('adminpager.js');
         echo $this->Html->script('recipetabs.js');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this for css

```
echo $html->css("style_rtl");
```

and for javascript file

```
echo $html->script("jquery");
```

no extension needed to load css and js, and make sure that css's are in css folder under webroot and js's are in js folder under webroot.
Thank you.

Comment: Thats how I have them no?, and they are under webroot/js and webroot/cs.. all work except that one in particular

Comment: You can try to copy your particular css content to a notepad and then save as name you wish. As mim type changed to another.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect cake isn't finding the jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css file and is instead returning it's missing file html page. If you have Firefox and Firebug installed, you can view the request that cakephp is sending back for the css file in the Net tab of Firebug.

Make sure you really DO have a file called "jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css" in your /app/webroot/css folder.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the file to something more simple (less . - #), see if it's still an issue.